# Django : content_type_id in GenericForeignKey

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-contenttypes

I wrote this class according to documentation to be able to vote on anything with an id in the application :

```
class Vote(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('voted_id', 'voter_id', 'content_type', 'vote_type')

    voted_id        = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    vote_type       = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    content_type    = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    voter_id        = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object  = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'voter_id')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content_object
```

Then in the database table, I have 5 columns :

```
id, voted_id, vote_type, voter_id, content_type_id
```

I don't really understand what is content_type_id referring to : is it a virtual id ?

Because in my understanding, when I wrote :

```
from forum.models import User, Vote
kdelanyd = User.objects.get(username='kdelanyd')
v = Vote(content_object=kdelanyd, voted_id=1, vote_type=False)
v.save()
```

I thought that content_type was holding 'kdelanyd' reference and then, somewhat its id : it does not.

Comment: It is the result of your `content_type = models.ForeignKey(...)`.

Comment: I find it rather strange that you do not make `voted_id` a `voted = ForeignKey(..)` since you do *not* embed that in a `GenericForeignKey(..)`.

Comment: as the result of content_type, is it completely indepent of the rest of the db ? and what do you mean by 'rather strange' ?

Comment: what do you mean with completely independent? You realize that a `ForeignKey` does not really exists at a database level? It is just a column that stores the value of the primary key it refers to, and it will, if the database has support for this, add a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint, so every `foo = ForeignKey(..)` means Django implictly creates a `foo_id` column (at the database, and it has logic at the Django side as well).

Comment: Furthermore is indeed strange that you store the `id` of the `voted` *not* voter, through an `id`. Typically if something "refers" to a model object, it is better to use a "relation" (like `ForeignKey`, `OneToOneField`, etc.)

Comment: so you mean that foo_id != referenced_object_id is perfectly normal ? and actually I added this column because I couldn't store the voted id as I thought : content_type_id != my voted_object_id , therefore my question.

Comment: no, the purpose of a `ForeignKey` is two-fold: (a) it enforces that the `foo_id` refers to a valid object (given the database supports `FOREIGN KEY` constraints), and (b) it provides a nice way to use relations, since you can say `Vote.voted` and obtain the person on which was voted.

Comment: you gonna think I'm thick.. That was rhetorical :) : I still don't understand how to get my voted object id from ContentType object.

Comment: in your `database`  maybe have table is `django_content_type`. And `content_type`, `content_type_id`, `content_object` reference in this table. Its use for define anything like "type" of you data. Like a `wheel`, it maybe of `car` or `bicycle`. In this case `car` and `bicycle` is a content_object. And id of `car` and `bicycle` in table  `django_content_type` is `content_type_id`

Comment: @NgocPham Thanks a lot for this explanation ! I will accept that as an answer if you put it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In your database maybe have table is `django_content_type`. And `content_type`, `content_type_id`, `content_object` reference in this table. Its use for define anything like "type" of your `data`.
- Like a `wheel`, it maybe wheel of `car` or `bicycle`. In this case `car` and `bicycle` is a `content_object`. And id of `car` and `bicycle` in table `django_content_type` is `content_type_id`