# How to estabilish ContentType relation in Django for Laravel Polymorphic related data?

Tags: django, django-models, django-contenttypes

I have a database that was created and working for the Laravel application, it contains a table with shared data for multiple models using "[Laravel Polymorphic Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships)"

For example, this is Comment model that contains comments for the Product, Post, Seller.

| id | commentable_type | commentable_id | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | App\Product | 1 | Comment text |
| 2 | App\Product | 2 | Comment text |
| 3 | App\Seller | 1 | Comment text |

I need to use this table in the Django application, I tried to create relation using ContentType Framework but no success because it's requires ContentType (int) relation to determine the model, but in the database, I have string values for `_type`.
Any suggestions on how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

After following the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations-1), you will see `content_type_id` in your polymorphic model's db table. This field references to the table `django_content_type.id` which is a list of models for each app in your project:

| id | app_label | model |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | auth | user |
| 2 | app | product |
| 3 | app | seller |

Django uses an **id** (int) reference to the parent model whereas Laravel saves the parent's **model class name** as a string field. This is why you will find `content_type_id` and not `content_type` once you migrate your migrations.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53861601) answer might also help you understand [Generic relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations-1) better.